# Automatic voting in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to vote automatically, and all the options are box-like as follow.

[image]

Before click the box, the html information is as follow.

[image]

After I select an option, the information is changed.

[image]

I try to vote by `requests`, like

```
r = requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

However, I cannot find the the submit data.

[image]

Any suggestion to acheive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can probably have a look at Selenium which is a Website Automation / Testing framework.

Using this you can open a headless browser environment and you can select elements and perform operations like click, scroll, etc